# How avoid object type declaration redundancy

Tags: typescript

Is there any way I can avoid the redundancy of defining a parameter without having to define its name twice (one for the actual use and one for its type)?

Eg. actually:

```
const sum({ a, b }: { a: number, b: number }) { ... }
```

As can be seen, I need to declare `a` and `b` twice, once as the deconstructed parameter name (`{ a, b }`) and the other time to define the expected type of the names (`{ a: number, b: number }`). Which seems redundant to me, in addition to the fact that in more complex cases the code maintenance is a little more affected.

I can avoid the inline definition if I create an interface for it:

```
interface SumParameters {
    a: number;
    b: number;
}

const sum({ a, b }: SumParameters) { ... }
```

Doing so improves the view if there are too many parameters, but doesn't solve the redundancy itself.

What I would like was to just do something like:

```
const sum({ a: number, b: number }) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that is a current limitation of TypeScript syntax when destructuring argument objects. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-use-x-in-the-destructuring-function-f-x-number------

There is a lengthy discussion on the TS repo (see [ms/TypeScript#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526)) with numerous proposals for improvement, but it does not look like the TS team is going to move towards any of them.